Costmap not published but robot navigates through the map
I am trying to simulate navigation on a differential drive robot in gazebo. I'm using the default config file for nav2 with the topic names changed. The navigation seems to work fine (navigates to goal poses without any issues) but when I echo or try to visualize the costmap there is no data on the topic.

The launch command I used for this is
ros2 launch nav2_bringup bringup_launch.py use_sim_time:=true use_composition:=False params_file:="/home/sriram/Desktop/study/diff_drive_ws/src/sim/params/nav2_params.yaml"  map:="/home/sriram/Desktop/study/diff_drive_ws/src/sim/maps/room_april_tag.yaml" 

The map was generated using slam_toolbox and the no parameters were changed.
Ps. Additional information below.


The configuration of the global and local cost map in the nav2_param.yaml file.
local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_footprint
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      footprint: "[ [0.700, 0.475], [0.700, -0.475], [-0.350, -0.475], [-0.350, 0.475] ]"
      robot_radius: 0.15
      plugins: ["voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: -0.01
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_footprint
      use_sim_time: True
      robot_radius: 0.15
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True

Gazebo reference to the sensor in the URDF file of the robot.
    <gazebo reference="base_scan">
        <sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <visualize>false</visualize>
        <update_rate>10</update_rate>
        <ray>
            <scan>
                <horizontal>
                    <samples>720</samples>
                    <resolution>1</resolution>
                    <min_angle>-3.14159</min_angle>
                    <max_angle>3.14159</max_angle>
                </horizontal>
                <vertical>
                    <samples>1</samples>
                    <resolution>1</resolution>
                </vertical>
            </scan>
            <range>
                <min>0.3</min>
                <max>30.0</max>
                <resolution>0.01</resolution>
            </range>
            <noise>
                <type>gaussian</type>
                <mean>0.0</mean>
                <stddev>0.01</stddev>
            </noise>0
        </ray>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so">
           <ros>
                <remapping>~/out:=scan</remapping>
           </ros>
           <output_type>sensor_msgs/LaserScan</output_type>
        </plugin>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>

Local cost map node info
/local_costmap/local_costmap
  Subscribers:
    /clock: rosgraph_msgs/msg/Clock
    /local_costmap/footprint: geometry_msgs/msg/Polygon
    /parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent
    /scan: sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan
  Publishers:
    /local_costmap/clearing_endpoints: sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2
    /local_costmap/costmap: nav_msgs/msg/OccupancyGrid
    /local_costmap/costmap_raw: nav2_msgs/msg/Costmap
    /local_costmap/costmap_updates: map_msgs/msg/OccupancyGridUpdate
    /local_costmap/local_costmap/transition_event: lifecycle_msgs/msg/TransitionEvent
    /local_costmap/published_footprint: geometry_msgs/msg/PolygonStamped
    /local_costmap/voxel_grid: nav2_msgs/msg/VoxelGrid
    /parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent
    /rosout: rcl_interfaces/msg/Log
  Service Servers:
    /local_costmap/clear_around_local_costmap: nav2_msgs/srv/ClearCostmapAroundRobot
    /local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap: nav2_msgs/srv/ClearEntireCostmap
    /local_costmap/clear_except_local_costmap: nav2_msgs/srv/ClearCostmapExceptRegion
    /local_costmap/get_costmap: nav2_msgs/srv/GetCostmap
    /local_costmap/local_costmap/change_state: lifecycle_msgs/srv/ChangeState
    /local_costmap/local_costmap/describe_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/DescribeParameters
    /local_costmap/local_costmap/get_available_states: lifecycle_msgs/srv/GetAvailableStates
    /local_costmap/local_costmap/get_available_transitions: lifecycle_msgs/srv/GetAvailableTransitions
    /local_costmap/local_costmap/get_parameter_types: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameterTypes
    /local_costmap/local_costmap/get_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameters
    /local_costmap/local_costmap/get_state: lifecycle_msgs/srv/GetState
    /local_costmap/local_costmap/get_transition_graph: lifecycle_msgs/srv/GetAvailableTransitions
    /local_costmap/local_costmap/list_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/ListParameters
    /local_costmap/local_costmap/set_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters
    /local_costmap/local_costmap/set_parameters_atomically: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParametersAtomically
  Service Clients:

  Action Servers:

  Action Clients:



Welcome to Robotics SriramK, but I'm afraid that it is not clear how to help you. Please edit the question to include a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question.  Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the Robotics question checklist to edit your question to make it clearer.

The problem was in the simulation. Gazebo was not publishing any message on the /clock topic, so the global and local cost map were not published. Fixing the clock topic in gazebo solved this
Changing the launch command to this fixed the issue.
ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['gzserver', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_init.so',
                '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so', default_world_path],
            cwd=[launch_dir], output='screen'),

            ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['gzclient'],
            cwd=[launch_dir], output='screen'),


oh interesting, Is there some reason for this happen? How did you fix?

I was launching gazebo with the launch command "gazebo -s libgazebo_ros_init.so -s libgazebo_ros_factory.so". Changing it launch the gazebo using "gzserver -s libgazebo_ros_init.so -s libgazebo_ros_factory.so" and "gzclient" separately solved the issue. (Maybe the plugins were not loaded while launching with gazebo? I'm not too sure)

ok I will add a new answer based on your data.
1- You need to check which is the topic name that your gazebo plugin (from urdf) is publishing
ros2 topic list

Let's suppose that on the list you found "hokuyo_scan"
I could not see from your urdf which topic is publishing since you did not remap to a specific topic name. I will show you an example that works
  <gazebo reference="left_lidar_link">
    <sensor name="left_lidar" type="ray">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>360</samples>
            <resolution>1.000000</resolution>
            <min_angle>0.000000</min_angle>
            <max_angle>6.280000</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.12</min>
          <max>100.0</max> 
          <resolution>0.015000</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.01</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="left_lidar_scan" filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so">
        <ros>
          <remapping>~/out:=left_scan</remapping>
        </ros>
        <output_type>sensor_msgs/LaserScan</output_type>
        <frame_name>left_lidar_link</frame_name>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

you can see that the topic which Gazebo is publishing sensor data for this example case is theleft_scan
2-Ok, now that you have identified your scan topic. You need to use it on your configuration file, but not as you did, you mixed the frame name with the topic name. I will show you the correct manner to define the sources. Look the example:
  obstacle_layer:
    plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
    enabled: True
    observation_sources: left_scan
    left_scan:
      topic: /left_scan
      max_obstacle_height: 2.0
      clearing: True
      marking: True
      data_type: "LaserScan"
      raytrace_max_range: 50.0
      raytrace_min_range: 0.0
      obstacle_max_range: 25.0
      obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      # outdoors there will probably be more inf points
      inf_is_valid: true

Pay attention that I used the left_scan topic name three times (3x)
You used scan in observation sources and below it (Twice) and used /gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller/out which seems to be you scan topic (I suppose). Did you check if this is the scan topic (if is coming raw laser data):
ros2 topic echo /gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller/out

Ok if is your topic you just need to fix this and do:
  observation_sources: gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller/out
    gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller/out:
      topic: /gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller/out

for both your local and global costmaps. After set this, it should work.

Hi, I tried what you have mentioned above but the issue still remains. I have now remapped the output topic to /scan and set the params to
observation_sources:scan
scan:
topic: /scan
But the issue still remains. In the node graph the local and global costmap are subscribing to the scan topic but there is no output on the costmap topic.

I have edited the post to reflect the changes I had done

Hi from your rosgraph (rqt output) it seems you have not any source for local/global costmap? It should be your base_scan topic to feed the local/global costmap, however it seems you are using a hokuyo controller (instead hokuyou sensor name topic, defined as output on your urdf gazebo plugin) in your configuration file?
Could I check you nav2_params.yaml and urdf files? I mean both local and global costmap should have a sensor as input, not a controller...
You can inspect which topics are the inputs of your local costmap issuing on your terminal something like
ros2 node info /local_costmap

your local_costmap should subscribe a sensor...
Your robot is just navigation because you have probably a previous static map loaded for this scenario. However it is not being able to create a real time costmap, since base_scan name topic (/hokuyo_sensor ?) is not declared as a source in your configuration file.

Hi, I have added the information, but it seems that the node is subscribed to the laser scan topic. Could you please have a look at this now?

I added a new answer, since it wouldn't be possible to detail in a comment. Take a look and check if it works...
